# replace all occurrences of words present in a text file with a dictionary key value pair python?

Tags: python, string, file, dictionary, replace

I have to replace several words in a txt file.
I have a dict constructed where all the keys that occur in the file should be replace with its value.

```
f1 = open('testlist01.txt', 'r')
f2 = open('new_testlist.txt', 'w')
for line1 in f1:
    for key1,value1 in new_class_names.iteritems():
        str(line1).replace(key1, str(value1))
    f2.write(line1)
    print line1
f1.close()
f2.close()
```

f1 contains

```
Archery/v_Archery_g09_c06.avi 3
BandMarching/v_BandMarching_g10_c06.avi 6
BasketballDunk/v_BasketballDunk_g19_c01.avi 9
```

f2 should be changed to

```
5/10 3
20/954 6
62/548 9
```

Where new_class_names is a dict for eg:-

```
{'Archery':5, 'BandMarching':20, 'BasketballDunk':62, 'v_Archery_g09_c06.avi':10 , 
'v_BandMarching_g10_c06.avi':954, 'v_BasketballDunk_g19_c01.avi':548}
```

The code I tried does not replace it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings in python are immutable. `str(line1).replace(key1, str(value1))` creates new string instance that gets lost. Assign the result to `line1` and it will do the job.

`str(line1).replace(key1, str(value1))` should become `line1 = line1.replace(key1, str(value1))`

Comment: Thanks :) That did it.